# Movie about a boy finding the girl('s spirit) and falling in love with her

Tags: story-identification, movie, love

I vaguely remember this story (which I saw a long time ago) where a guy meets this new girl while all alone on a bridge at night. She comes into his life and makes everything alright about him. He becomes the coolest guy and everything turns out well; all because of this girl. I think the plot revolves around finding out how she was killed by a car accident at the bridge. 
Then she has to go, I don't remember the reason why. I think she goes away from him forever near that bridge mentioned earlier. I do remember that the last scene of this movie was that this guy finds out that a new girl which has come to school is the real girl who hasn't ever met this guy. She has the same name but doesn't know the guy at all. I also remember that the whole story was set in the 60s or 70s and the girl was from the previous decade. I also remember that the guy was wearing white coat when he met the girl.
Can somebody please identify this movie for me please? I would love to watch it again; was an unusual love story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this movie is [Susie Q](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susie_Q_(film)).

The movie is about a boy that's having various issues, and finds the dead girl's bracelet that enables him to see her ghost. The girl died 40 years earlier in a car accident near a bridge. Her ghost ends up being involved in the lead boy's home and school life.

**Note the white sleeves on the movie poster**
[image]

Per the Wiki synopsis, the movie's final scene:

> In the closing scene, Zach meets a girl who looks identical to Susie and who introduces herself as Maggie.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the edit with the pic. It's cumbersome for me to add external media when I use the SE app, and I haven't had time to get on here on my PC/laptop and do it myself.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! CreationEdge and Richard... I have been looking for this movie for a long time and here I ask the question and get the answer within a day! Stack Exchange is AWESOME! (I know 'Thank You' comments are generally discouraged but couldn't stop myself). Thanks again. :D